# Python SOAP client library

Tags: library, python, web-services, soap

I need to write my own client to interact with a service that only exposes a SOAP interface.  My preferred language is Python, especially since I've already written a bunch of code that I'll need to use for this project.

When I look around for SOAP client libraries for Python it seems like there is nothing that is being currently developed or maintained.

- [ZSI](http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/) - last updated in 2013
- [SUDs](https://fedorahosted.org/suds/) - last updated in 2012
- [SOAPy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapy/) - last updated in 2013
- [soaplib](https://github.com/soaplib/soaplib) - last updated in 2013

I'll be using Python 2 ideally under Cygwin.  If Cygwin becomes a limitation though, I'll jump to another platform very quickly, and already have several flavors of Linux at the ready (but the software I'm connecting to requires Silverlight in the browser so I'm doing my initial work on a Windows system).

The most promising lead seems to be [Spyne](https://github.com/arskom/spyne) but that looks like it does a lot of other things and carries many other dependencies, so may not be a great fit for just wanting a client SOAP library.

Answer (score 4):

Even though this probably won't help you now, it might help someone.

- It appears there is a fork of [suds](https://bitbucket.org/jurko/suds) that is still being developed as of Feb. 2016. I've used it before and liked it.
- [rinse](https://github.com/tysonclugg/rinse) which seems to be a minimal library. It was last updated in 2015.
- There is also [pysimplesoap](https://github.com/pysimplesoap/pysimplesoap) which was also updated Feb. 2016.
- [zeep](http://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/) is probably your best choice these days since it was updated May 2017